# R: non-conformable arguments

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to multiply a 2x2 matrix with 1x2 matrix.

```
class(logP)
# "array"
dim(logP)
# 2 2 1
class(theta[,t-1,1])
# "numeric"
dim(theta[,t-1,1])
# NULL
length(theta[,t-1,1])
# 2
logP%*%theta[,t-1,1]
# Error in logP %*% theta[, t - 1, 1] : non-conformable arguments
```

`logP` is 2x2 while `theta[,t-1,1]` is 2x1. How should I perform matrix multiplication with them?

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: No, `dim(theta[,t-1,1])` is NULL. You lost the dimension. You need to use drop=FALSE. Look at `dim(theta[,t-1,1, drop=FALSE])` for comparison and then go to `?"["` to improve your knowledge of that most crucial of  functions behavior and parameters to control them.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that logP is a 2X2X1 array. You should convert it to a matrix using `drop`.

Here is a reproducible example that replicates your problem.

```
# the identity matrix stored as a 2X2X1 array
logP <- array(c(1, 0, 0, 1), c(2,2,1))
# some vector
theta <- 1:2
```

Inspecting the objects as in the post

```
dim(logP)
[1] 2 2 1
dim(theta)
NULL
```

Make sure we properly set up the identity matrix

```
logP
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1
```

Now, try the multiplication

```
logP %*% theta
```

> Error in logP %*% theta : non-conformable arguments

Since the third dimension is 1, we can get rid of it using `drop`.

```
drop(logP) %*% theta
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
```

which returns what we would expect a 2X1 matrix with the values of theta.